# Source code for Guacamole/Guacamole docker image

Tags: docker-image, guacamole

I am building docker images for guacamole . There is an image in docker repo tagged as guacamole/guacamole . i wanted to know if there is a way to get the source code for the docker image

Answer (score 1):

You can get it [here](https://github.com/apache/guacamole-client/tree/master/guacamole-docker), in the [official repository](https://github.com/apache/guacamole-client) of Guacamole.